# When a custom renderer is set to a jTable does it work everytime it is updated?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a custom renderer to set background color to every row in a constantly updating jTable depending on a certain value, thing is I'm not sure if I should set the custom renderer after setting a new model to the jTable or if it's fine setting it only once after initializing it.

EDIT: Making a more precise question: Where should I set the custom renderer?

Comment: You will need to reapply all renderers/editors when ever you change the model, as they are actually associated with the table's `TableColumnModel` which is reset base on the information in the new `TableModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reapply all renderers/editors when ever you change the model, as they are actually associated with the table's `TableColumnModel` which is reset based on the information in the new `TableModel`

You might consider updating the contents of the model instead of applying a new one if you can, it's less of disruption to the UI (generally) and to the user

Comment: I'm updating the contents in the model and then applying the modified model to the jTable. What I want to know is, after setting the custom renderer to a table does it stay as it's renderer even if I modify the table content by setting an updated model? Should I set it just once?

Comment: ANY time you call `setModel`, it will reset the `TableColumnModel` (and a bunch of other things), which means you MUST reset you renders and editors after you do so.  It would be better if you could update the live model and simply let the table update in response, this way, you won't need to completely revalidate the entire table every time